# Upload images to remote servers. PHP

Tags: php, image, upload

I do the image hosting and I have a problem..

I have 3 servers.

First - Site/script

Any two servers for images.

How I Can upload image from "one" server (script) to second and third servers?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
        $blacklist = array('.php', '.phtml', '.php3', '.php4', '.php5');
        foreach ($blacklist as $item)
        {
            if(preg_match('#' . $item . '\$#i', $_FILES['file']['name']))
            {
                echo "We do not allow uploading PHP files\n";
                exit;
            }
        }

        $uploadDir  = PROJECT_ROOT . 'upload/'; // 1ST SERVER (THIS SERVER)
        $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile))
        {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "File uploading failed.\n";
        }
    }    
?>
<form name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select the file to upload: <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you attempting to sync the images across the three servers, or ?

Comment: @middaparka, I do image hosting. When you load an image that it should be poured on any one of 3 servers. 3 servers need to unload the channel. Later there will be more servers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unload the channel". That said, if you're try to replicate an image across all three servers, I'd be tempted to use something like [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ftp. PHP has fairly easy way to do this. Check this link.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Answer (score 0):

If you already have HTTP servers runing on the other servers, use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Usage:

1. Call [curl_init](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)
2. Call [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)
3. Call [curl_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)

The HTTP request can be configured using [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). Especially of interest are the options CURLOPT_URL, CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: That is, you have to offer on two other servers to host scripts, and the first to use Curl to send images?

Comment: @Isis I assumed you have that already. If you don't, go with FTP as dqhendricks suggested or some other protocol that the other servers already offer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zend_Http Client to upload the files to other servers per HTTP the same way an HTML Upload Form would do it. You can find all the information you need here in the Section "File Uploads": http://www.zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html

For getting started you should read also this:

http://www.zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html

Basically the code you need is:

```
require_once('Zend/Http/Client.php');
$client = new Zend_Http_Client("http://serverurl/path");
$client->setFileUpload(...);
$client->request();
```