# Upload same Image one server to another server using php

Tags: php

I search this question in Stackoverflow but I don't understand the answer. Sorry.

Well, I've a html upload form which handle by Php.

**Following is my php upload script :**

```
if($image["name"] != "")
{
//$path = PATH . DS . "uploads" . DS . "products" . DS . $id;
$path = "../../uploads" . DS . "products" . DS . $id;
if(!is_dir($path))
{
    mkdir($path);
}
chmod($path, 0755);
//move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], $path . DS . $image["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], $path . DS . $uploadImage);//exit;
}
```

Now I'm trying to upload same image to Another website folder. Like : www.mysitename/folder/finalfolder. in the same time with Php.

Is there any way to upload it another website ?

Comment: you could use sockets and make the other server listen a port in which it could receive the raw data of the uploaded image

Comment: Use cURL http://www.php.net/curl

Comment: @Oddant I don't understand your point. I'm new in PHP.

Comment: @AlexMojum consider Andrey Volk's answer

Comment: Have the first server upload to the second, the second should have some checks to only accept uploads from the first server.

Comment: use curl to to an http upload to the other server, or use another means of transfer, e.g. scp/sftp and directly put the file into the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other server will need a script to handle the request. You can then POST that data to the other server's script using a CURL request. (See the link posted by @Andrey Volk)

Or, as suggested here: [FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775376) will work too, if you have that level of access to the server.

Comment: For the CURL method, the script on the other server should be very similar to the script on the originating server, yes.

Comment: If I have time later, I'll dig up some old files and fix the link mentioned here:[TecBrat Blog](http://tecbrat.blogspot.com/2007/12/curl-multipart-from-data-file-upload.php) At the moment, the blog page links to a non-existent page on my site.

Comment: I fixed the link I mentioned in the comment above.